# Multi-line editing on Atom

Tags: multiline, atom-editor

I have this task that I need to complete fast as possible. I have coupon codes **(over 1000)**, I going to create an array out of it. To do that fast as possible I need to be able select multiples lines and edit them at the same time. I am using Atom as my editor choice. I tried to search online for answers but non found.

```
ST55672
SE82673
SS85074
SD65675
SH75676
```

**to:**

```
"ST55672",
"SE82673",
"SS85074",
"SD65675",
"SH75676",
```

PS. Im using Mac

Comment: I'm aware notepad++ allows you to do this, as well as sublime text, haven't tried doing it in Atom yet. Couldn't you write a small script to do that though? I imagine editing 1000+ lines in an editor regardless of which editor you do it in, isn't very pleasant. P.S. The script'll probably take you about 8-10 lines.

Comment: You can use emacs style macros with atom-ymacs ( https://atom.io/packages/ymacs-editor ).  Start a macro with ctrl-x ( , quote the string, end the macro with ctrl-x ) and save back to atom.  You can execute the macro 1000 times by typing ctrl-u 1000 ctrl-x e .

Comment: I don't think Notepad++ is on Mac

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**1. Atom Commands**

Select all text (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> elsewhere), then use the shortcut to *“split the selection into lines”* (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> elsewhere). Both commands are also available from the [command palette](http://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/atom-basics/#command-palette).

PS: like many other keyboard shortcuts, these also work in Sublime Text

**2. RegEx Search & Replace**

Search for `^(.*)$` and replace with `"$1",`.

Comment: I think that should be `^(.*)$` to ensure string capture to `$1`.

Comment: Thank you so much idleberg! I tried the first one and it worked!

Comment: On Windows and Linux, there is no shortcut for `split selection into lines`.  `ctrl+shift+L` is mapped to something else.  You have to select it from the `selection` menu on the top bar.

Comment: If there is no `Ctrl+Shift+L` shortcut, you can add it as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352923/atom-editor-keyboard-shortcut-for-split-selections-into-lines).

Answer (score 1):

Notice for windows users:

multiline cursor works using these keys in the following order :

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>[image]</kbd>

and <kbd>↓</kbd>, or <kbd>↑</kbd>, or a mouse "Click" any where you need

Answer (score 0):

> 1. select all lines
> 2. Go to `selection` menu on the top bar (win & Linux)
> 3. select `split selection into lines`