# Atom Editor Keyboard Shortcut for Split Selections into Lines

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

In the Atom editor the default behavior for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is to *select-grammar*. I have successfully changed this to *split-selections-into-lines*. How do I now assign *select-grammar* to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>?

I put the following in my keymap.cson file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is working, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> does nothing at this point.

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-shift-L': 'editor:split-selections-into-lines'
  'ctrl-shift-J': 'editor:select-grammar'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-shift-L': 'editor:split-selections-into-lines'
  'ctrl-shift-J': 'grammar-selector:show'
```

Comment: ~3 years later and this is still accurate. If anyone sees this and doesn't know about the keymap.cson, the current version lets you edit it via Preferences->Keybindings. Save and restart atom for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

try to map it in the key binder resolver, like this:

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
   'ctrl-shift-j': 'editor:select-grammar'

'atom-text-editor':
   'ctrl-shift-j': 'editor:select-grammar'
```

or

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-shift-j': 'unset!'

'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-shift-j': 'editor:select-grammar'
```

don´t forgett to save and restart atom.